# Dynamically accepted the Reviews and Rating

Tags: product, admin, review, ratings

I want to approve the reviews or rating without admin manual approval.Means i don't want that admin approve all the pending rating but as rating comes it got approved.I have searched the admin panel for this option and on Google but no luck.As there any default method or i have to code for that ?

Comment: override review module and when review in save in magento set status to complete simple

Comment: thanks for response.Means no default option available for this ?

Comment: yes no options available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to take a look at this post on the MagentCommerce boards:

[Automatically approving ratings and/or reviews](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/264907/)

He goes into full detail and includes all relevant source code to do this programmatically via your own extension.